# Would or could it be a public order offence (racially/religiously aggravated or otherwise) to burn or mutilate a national flag or a holy scripture?

Tags: united-kingdom, freedom-of-speech, is-x-legal, any-jurisdiction, public-order

In the UK, Alice burns a Quran on a public pavement.

Bob tears up an Irish flag.

Do either of these commit public order offences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [No](https://www.dpp-law.com/services/criminal-defence/public-order-offences/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20a%20public%20order,intimidation%20by%20individuals%20or%20groups.) in the UK

Or, at least, not of itself, but it could be part of a pattern of conduct that is.

> The Crown Prosecution Service defines a public order offence as an act that involves the use of violence and/or intimidation by individuals or groups.

Answer (score 5):

In the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states), neither is a crime in and of itself.

[*Texas v. Johnson*, 491 U.S. 397 (1989)](https://casetext.com/case/texas-v-johnson).

Answer (score 1):

bdb484's answer that "neither is a crime in and of itself." is not quite right, and in a way, the answer for the US is the opposite: burning a book, in and of itself, can be criminalized, but criminalizing the *reason* for doing it raises constitutional questions. There is absolutely no constitutional bar to a generally applicable, content neutral law against setting things on fire in public. It's only when the book-burners are treated differently based on what their bonfires express that free speech comes up. So if a Quran burner is prosecuted, but a phone book burner is not, then the Quran burner has a constitutional argument available to them.